# Function with 3 arguments: Return result after applying operator i.e. (5, 7, '+') = 35

Tags: function, arguments, expression, evaluate

Hopefully my title explains it but I need a function that will take 3 arguments (two numbers and an operator [*, +, /, -]), then compute the result.

Something like this:

```
function evaluateExpression (firstNum, secondNum, operator) {
    ...
    return ...;
}

evaluateExpression (35, 7, '/'); // should return 5
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Use an if statement to check the operator, then evaluate statement if true.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have no idea where to start, write a list of how you would do this (broken down into as much detail as possible) and then write code corresponding to each item in the list.

Comment: This question has been solved by Hayley Guillou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
evaluateExpression( first, second, op ) :

    if op == "+" :
         return first + second

    else if op == "*" :
         return first * second

    ... etc

    else :
         return error
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
if (operator === "+") { return firstNum + secondNum };
if (operator === "-") { return firstNum - secondNum };
if (operator === "/") { return firstNum / secondNum }; 
if (operator === "*") { return firstNum * secondNum }; 
if (operator === "%") { return firstNum % secondNum };
```

Another way:

```
switch (operator) {
  case "+" : return firstNum + secondNum;
  case "-" : return firstNum - secondNum;
  case "/" : return firstNum / secondNum;
  case "*" : return firstNum * secondNum;
  case "%" : return firstNum % secondNum;
}
```

If you are using javascript, this could be another way:

```
eval(firstNum + operator + secondNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even in python, you can use the eval method. Just convert the operands to strings and call the function.

evaluateExpression( first, second, op ) :

```
return eval(str(first) + op + str(second))
```